# CTest doesn't find gcov library

Tags: gcov, ctest

I am trying to use CDash to send test results to a dashboard. It currently can't find gcov.

```
garrett% ctest -D Experimental     
Site: 
Build name: (empty)
Create new tag: 21170910-5324 - Experimental
Configure project
Cannot find ConfigureCommand key in the DartConfiguration.tcl
Build project
Cannot find MakeCommand key in the DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project    
    Start 1: os
1/2 Test #1: os ............................   Passed   73.42 sec
    Start 2: io
2/2 Test #2: io ............................   Passed   80.85 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) = 154.28 sec
Performing coverage
Could not find gcov.
```

I tried to run coverage before and was getting an error saying it could not find the -lgcov library.

when I run gcov -version I get:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Optimized build.
Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
```

I know it uses GCC, could I possibly not have the correct version? I followed the Kitware documentation to run code coverage - changing the flags, etc.